# Regular Expression for 11 digits number with leading zero

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate textbox with minimum 11 digits to enter with regex I had used below regex

```
^[0-9]{11}$
```

It's only working for non leading zero digits if I enter any number with zero leading I'm getting Validation failed error in my model

My Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateClient(CompanyClient client)
    {
        var result = _dal.AddClient(client);
        if (result)
        {
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My DAL

```
public bool AddClient(CompanyClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                client.Status = StatusEnum.Enabled;
                client.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                client.CreatedBy = CurrentUserName;
                context.ICompanyClient.Add(client);
                context.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

MY Class

```
public class CompanyClient
{
    public int CompanyClientId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Client Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Client Name is required")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Company Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Email  is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                        @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                        @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                        ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
    public string CompanyEmailId { get; set; }

    //[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [DisplayName("Telephone No")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone No  is required")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{11,}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 11 digits")]
    public long Tel { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fax No")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{11,}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 11 digits")]
    public long? FaxNo { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Mobile No")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 10 digits")]
    public long? MobileNo { get; set; }
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
    public string CompanyLocation { get; set; }
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: `^[0-9]{11}$` will allow 0 at start also.

Comment: Can you show us the code itself? This regexp enables leading zeros.

Comment: how should i show i'm getting error in model while saving

Comment: if i enter non leading zero i'm able to save value

Comment: Show us the C# code where you are validating the entered value.

Comment: I got it from your comment to the first answer. You are not using C# with regexp, you are using MVC DataAnnotation. Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: @Light: What version of MVC are you using and what is the data type you are decorating with the regularexpression validation?

Comment: I am pretty confident the problem is that you strip leading `0`s before you convert the input to string to test it with a regex pattern.

Comment: MVC 4 [DisplayName("Telephone No")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone No  is required")]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{11,}", ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 11 digits")]
        public long Tel { get; set; }

Comment: @Light: If you are using long then there are no leading zeros, because it is a numeric format. Try to use just plain string.

Comment: note telephone numbers should be allowed to contain `+` and possibly even space characters.. and they can be less than 11 characters long

Comment: @Biri,@Aprillion thank you i will change to string

Answer (score 4):

For minimum 11 digits, you need to use the below pattern,

```
^[0-9]{11,}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oY5nA8/13)

[image]

Comment: still getting validate error i had used like this  [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{11,}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least 11 digits")]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
^[0-9]{11,}
```

it worked when I tried..

Comment: i'm using this only but no luck

Comment: @Light did you try removing the $ at the end?

Comment: also change `public long Tel { get; set; }` to `public long? Tel { get; set; }`

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: it does not help. The problem is that you cannot add leadin zeroes to a numerical value. Int 01 is 1, long 02 is 2. You need a string to have it.